# How can I define abilities with a JSON using CASL

Tags: javascript, casl

I have been reading the documentation of the CASL library and apparently you can define the abilities using a JSON with something like this:

```js
import { Ability } from '@casl/ability';

export default new Ability([
  {
    action: 'read',
    subject: 'Post'
  },
  {
    action: 'delete',
    subject: 'Post',
    conditions: { published: true },
    inverted: true
  }
])
```

But right now I'm trying a dummy example like this and it doesn't work, not sure why:

```js
import { Ability } from '@casl/ability';
const ability = new Ability([{ action: 'read', subject: 'article' }], {
    detectSubjectType:subject => subject.subject
})
console.log(ability.can('read', {subject: 'article'})); // Returns false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from 4.0, CASL supports classes as subjects. Because of this `detectSubjectType` is called for each rule at `Ability` creation time in order to detect type of the subject.

In your case, the function handles only passed subjects as objects (with `subject` field) but it should also work properly with strings.

You have 2 options here:

- check if subject is a string and if so return it as it's

```js
const ability = new Ability([{ action: 'read', subject: 'article' }], {
   detectSubjectType: subject => typeof subject === 'string' ? subject : subject.subject
})
```

- use default `detectSubjectType` as fallback

```js
import { Ability, detectSubjectType } from '@casl/ability';
const ability = new Ability([{ action: 'read', subject: 'article' }], {
   detectSubjectType: subject => subject && subject.subject ? subject.subject : detectSubjectType(subject)
})
```

In section [Custom subject type detection](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/v4/en/guide/subject-type-detection#custom-subject-type-detection), the docs says:

Custom detection function must return `string` and handle the next cases:

- when `subject` is `undefined`
- when `subject` is a `string` or a `function` (this should be perceived as a subject type)
- when subject is an `object`

If you don't want to handle all that cases, you can fallback to built-in `detectSubjectType` function which will do this for you.

Comment: Strange enough, with a little tweak your answer works for me in ExpressJS:  `let a = new Ability(rules); 
    a.detectSubjectType = subject => {
        return subject && subject.subject ? subject.subject : detectSubjectType(subject);
    };`